# Pagespeed doesn't apply correctly on Web Page Source Code. Module enabled on apache

Tags: php, html, apache, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have pagespeed module installed on Apache server and a website developed on codeigniter.

As I want to enable pagespeed only on few domain hosted on server. In **`.htaccess`** file have used below code to enable pagespeed :

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed on 
</IfModule>
```

I am facing below problems :

1. CSS files isn't getting rewrite or cached by pagespeed :
   For eg: The css file after a proper pagespeed application should appear like :

**`https://domainname.com/assets/css/A.common.css,qv=15.35.pagespeed.cf.Biz8Hjcmz6.css`**

But it still appears to be like :

**`https://domainname.com/assets/css/common.css`**

2. CSS files are not getting merged.
3. JS files are not getting rewrite or getting merged 
   For eg: The js file after a proper pagespeed application should appear like

**`https://domainname.com/assets/js/A.main.js,qv=15.35.pagespeed.cf.Biz8Hjcmz6.js`**

But it still appears to be like :

**`https://domainname.com/assets/js/main.js`**

4. Images are not getting rewrite or cached using pagespeed.

For eg: Image tag should get **"data-pagespeed-url-hash"** attribute or image url gets pagespeed cached name, which doesn't appear to be applying.

Can anyone help. Whats going wrong ?

Comment: Do you know for sure that the module is running? Is the `X-Mod-Pagespeed` header being added to the responses? Are there definitely any active filters?

Comment: Yes got this : "X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.12.34.1-0"

Executed this code : curl -D- https://domainname.com | less

Comment: No filters added in .htaccess. 

Pagespeed appears on source code but is applied to only 1 gif image added in CSS style tag. .slick-slide{background:transparent url(/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif.pagespeed.ce.gnHdLcevAc.gif) no-repeat scroll center center}.